# отправка push в pwa на ios

Tags: веб-программирование, ios, уведомления, push, pwa

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста по поводу push в pwa на ios, сейчас все выглядит так - [Демо push](https://wdc-dev.ru/push)

мне нужно чтобы например по событию в приложении (новое сообщение) приходило уведомления на айфон, вне зависимости от того, открыто приложение или нет, висит он в фоне или нет, находиться ли телефон в спящем режиме и тд., без использования платных сервисов и без оплаты APNS и сертификатов для apple, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: firebase, но без сертификата  для apple все равно не обойтись